# Aproximation lg(n!)=n(lgn)-0.434)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, approximation, factorial

I should use this approximation in order to find the value of this combination of 78 elements, class 19 without using a calculator. I have no idea how can I write n! in another way in order to use it. Please help me! Thanks! [image]

Comment: It seems that to use this approximation you'll need to compute logs without a calculator... BTW, is $\lg=\log_2$?

Comment: Math.stackexchange.com is not a calculator, nor is [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=78+choose+19) or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=78+choose+19).

Comment: @lhf It must be $\log_{10}$.

Comment: @Ihf it is log with basis 10,

Comment: the formula, as copied in the title of your problem, does not correctly represent the formula in the statement of the problem. Please correct the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\binom{78}{19}$$
$$=>y=\frac{78!}{19!\times59!}$$
$$=>\lg{y}=\lg{78!}-\lg{19!}+\lg{59!}$$

$$y=10^{\lg{78!}-\lg{19!}+\lg{59!}}$$

Now you can use the approximation formula to calculate the rest of it.